# Docker ElasticSearch 5 does not start . Even ELK does not start

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, elasticsearch-5

elasticsearch:5 does not start. Getting following error :

```
max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] likely too low, increase to at least [262144]
```

I tried many combinations like setting Xms, Xmx etc. Nothing helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your Unix; firstly run

```
$ sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

to increase map count. After that run your docker container. Will run like a charm